# What certificate do I need for code signing?

Tags: clickonce, certificate, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I'm trying to sign a ClickOnce .NET Application. I have a SSL cert that I use on a website, but I'm thinking that it is not up to the job. When I select the cert in Visual Studio I get an messsage box saying '*The selected certificate is not valid for code signing. Choose another certificate file*'.
The cert details look like this:

[image]

whereas a temporary cert generated in VS looks like this:

[image]

It seems to have a lot more going for it in terms of looks and general charisma. 
Do I need to get a new cert issued? What would I need to specify when ordering it to ensure it is up to the job of signing the ClickOnce code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certificates that you buy usually have a single purpose.  There are several companies out there that provide code signing certificates (I bought one from GoDaddy! a few years ago).

The Adsense results on a single Google search should be enough to get you going:

http://www.google.com/search?q=code+signing

Answer (score 1):

This company http://www.instantssl.com/code-signing/ is the cheapest place I found for code signing certs.  I had no problem going through the purchasing process.

Comment: Godaddy seems cheaper. Godaddy: $199 per 1yr. InstantSSL: €179/$244 per 1yr

Comment: Huh?  When I follow the link it says $179/year for 1 year.  That seems cheaper than $199.

Comment: If you use anyone but Verisign you will not be allowed to pick up your crash dumps from Windows Error Reporting (http://connect.microsoft.com/site831/feedback/details/531903/allow-other-certificates-in-winqual-not-only-verisign)

Comment: @IanBoyd link is now broken, sadly.